# when i enter correct username and password all program ends... why?

Tags: vb.net

When I enter correct username and password all program ends and I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click       
    If username.Text = My.Settings.username And password.Text = My.Settings.pass Then
        form2.Show()
        Me.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("خطأ في كلمة السر او اسم المستخدم", , "خطأ")
    End If
```

Comment: Explicitely call the close VIA the form name?

Comment: it says vannot refer to it self use me instead

Comment: Because you closed your main form.  Project + Properties, change the Shutdown mode setting to "When last form closes".

Comment: what do you mean by this ??

Comment: @user2780962 .. try to not using your login form as mainform ..

Answer (score 2):

Is `Me` your startup form?

If that's the case, `Me.Close()` is effectively terminating your application.

You can get around this as follows:

```
form2.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Hans Passant actually provided the better solution (my VB is a bit rusty). Go into Project Properties, and change the Shutdown mode.

Comment: i'm change it but login form still exist